Confused on how to mathematically, without computing, find the amount of times u can spell "RADAR" in the given image if u can go any direction.
RADAR Image for the question
                    ["R"],                                   # Row 1
               ["R", "A", "R"],                              # Row 2
          ["R", "A", "D", "A", "R"],                         # Row 3
     ["R", "A", "D", "A", "D", "A","R"],                     # Row 4
["R", "A", "D", "A", "R", "A", "D", "A", "R"],               # Row 5
     ["R", "A", "D", "A", "D", "A", "R"],                    # Row 6
          ["R", "A", "D", "A", "R"],                         # Row 7
               ["R", "A", "R"],                              # Row 8
                    ["R"]                                    # Row 9

You can move in any direction from any R in the image and you must spell out RADAR, the only restriction is that you cannot use a cell that was already used in your spelling of the word RADAR. How many ways can you possibly spell RADAR--again any direction is fair game, diagonals, up, down, left, right, you just cannot overlap.
I understand how to solve this with a DFS through computing but how would you go about solving this with combinatorics?
Enjoy!

Focus on the D's.

Note that RADAR only has one "D" in it, so it is easier if we analyze by every occurrence of the letter "D". From there, we need to find two unique branches of "AR's" stemming from the "D". Since we have symmetry around both axes and rotationally, there are only two cases of "D's" we must consider:
Case 1: "D" is on the middle row or middle column (i.e. R3C5, R5C3, R5C7, R7C5).
Each of these 4 "D's" are functionally identical, since we can rotate our grid and it will look the same. For simplicity, let's look at the highest of these four options: R3C5. There are four different "A's" stemming from this node: up, down, left, and right. It is slightly bashy, but we can simply divide into cases based on which 2 "A's" are chosen.
(Up, Right): 3 choices of "R" for the top "A" and 2 choices for the right "A" minus one case where they overlap on the same "R". Thus $3 \cdot 2 - 1 = 5$.
(Up, Left): By symmetry, 5.
(Up, Down): 3 choices for the top "A" and 1 for the bottom "A": 3.
(Left, Right): 2 choices for each: 4.
(Left, Down): 2 choices for the left and 1 for the bottom: 2.
(Right, Down): By symmetry, 2.
Adding all of these results in 21 unique RADAR's using that "D".
Since there are 4 "D's" in Case 1, we multiply $21 \cdot 4 = 84$ "RADAR's" in Case 1.
Case 2: A very similar idea can be applied where "D" is R4C4, R4C6, R6C4, R6C6.
We will just look at the "D" in R4C4 and multiply our results by 4.
There are again the 6 different subcases for our "A's":
(Up, Right) - 2
(Up, Left) - 3
(Up, Down) - 2
(Left, Right) - 2
(Left, Down) - 2
(Right, Down) - 0
This gives us $11 \cdot 4 = 44$ "RADAR's" in Case 2.
Summing these two cases results in 128 unique "RADAR" strings. Since each instance of "RADAR" in the grid can be spelled out forward or backward, we multiply $128 \cdot 2 = 256$ total ways to spell RADAR.

Thanks for the awesome reply! Would it be times 2 after because RADAR can be spelled backwards too?

@IffatIqbal Yes! You are correct, I've edited my answer to account for this now.
